# Circular Queue That has a display function that displays even numbers only

Tags: c++, numbers, queue

hi so i have this circular queue c++ program i need its display function only displays even inserted numbers only can someone here help please here's the code

**i need a way that this program only displays even numbers only i'v been trying to use the %2==0 on some location that might make sense but mostly i get them wrong or empty**
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int cqueue[5];
int front = -1, rear = -1, n=5;

void insertCQ(int val) {
   if ((front == 0 && rear == n-1) || (front == rear+1)) {
      cout<<"Queue Overflow \n";
      return;
   }
   if (front == -1) {
      front = 0;
      rear = 0;
   } else {
      if (rear == n - 1)
      rear = 0;
      else
      rear = rear + 1;
   }
   cqueue[rear] = val ;
}
void deleteCQ() {
   if (front == -1) {
      cout<<"Queue Underflow\n";
      return ;
   }
   cout<<"Element deleted from queue is : "<<cqueue[front]<<endl;

   if (front == rear) {
      front = -1;
      rear = -1;
   } else {
      if (front == n - 1)
      front = 0;
      else
      front = front + 1;
   }
}
void displayCQ() {
   int f = front, r = rear;
   if (front == -1) {
      cout<<"Queue is empty"<<endl;
      return;
   }
   cout<<"Queue elements are :\n";
   if (f <= r) {
      while (f <= r){
         cout<<cqueue[f]<<" ";
         f++;
      }
   } else {
      while (f <= n - 1) {
         cout<<cqueue[f]<<" ";
         f++;
      }
      f = 0;
      while (f <= r) {
         cout<<cqueue[f]<<" ";
         f++;
      }
   }
   cout<<endl;
}
int main() {

   int ch, val;
   cout<<"1)Insert\n";
   cout<<"2)Delete\n";
   cout<<"3)Display\n";
   cout<<"4)Exit\n";
do {
   cout<<"Enter choice : "<<endl;
   cin>>ch;
   switch(ch) {
      case 1: 
         cout<<"Input for insertion: "<<endl;
         cin>>val;
         insertCQ(val);
         break;

      case 2: 
         deleteCQ();
         break;

      case 3: 
         displayCQ();
         break;

      case 4: 
         cout<<"Exit\n";
         break;
         default: cout<<"Incorrect!\n";
   }
} while(ch != 4);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and hence not fully understandable. Please improve the grammatical usage and format of your sentences in the question.

Comment: Can you use `%2==0` to pick off all even entries in a regular array? If not, start there and only move on to the more complicated case when you have the simple case worked out.

Comment: I think you should show the code that uses `(%2 == 0)` so we can help fix that. It does not appear in your code.

Comment: You have an array. Barely an array list. Nothing is circular. A queue can be implemented using an array, but you haven't really implemented a queue. Your delete function doesn't seem to handle an array with a single element correctly. Typically, displaying all elements of a queue involves emptying the queue as you display it. Otherwise it's not a queue, it's a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example using `std::queue`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
  // This deque is declared just to more easily instantiate the queue
  std::deque<int> deck{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  std::queue<int> q{deck};

  while (!q.empty()) {
    if (q.front() % 2 == 0) {
      std::cout << q.front() << ' ';
    }
    q.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

You were on the right path using mod 2, but everything about your "queue" is not correct. To put it simply, you have not written a queue, and definitely not a circular queue.

Queues are FIFO data structures; first in, first out. Think of it like a tunnel. I will only add elements to one end, and I will only remove elements from the other. Everything in the middle does not matter, except to know the size of the queue. This means that the *only* visible elements are the first and last. If I want to see the second element of the queue, I must remove the first element.

The code you've written treats your array like a list instead where you have free access to all elements.

It's better to write an actual queue class, and I would hope that if you're writing data structures, that you are able to write a class.

Here's an extremely basic queue class that exhibits the behavior you are asking about. There is nothing circular about it. The word circular implies that your queue should be implemented with a circular linked list and not an array. It's worth noting that it requires at least C++11, but that really shouldn't be a problem today.

**IMPORTANT**
This code leaves out a lot of necessary error-checking. For example, `back()` will likely lead to undefined behavior if called on an empty queue, among other things. This was intentional to avoid a flat-out copy/paste being employed because cheating on homework is bad.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace Q {
class queue {
public:
  int &front() { return m_arr[0]; }
  int &back() { return m_arr[m_size - 1]; }

  void push(int val) {
    if (m_size < 5) {
      m_arr[m_size] = val;
      ++m_size;
    }
  }

  // Shifts entire array one to the left
  void pop() {
    if (m_size > 0) {
      for (int i = 1; i < m_size; ++i) {
        m_arr[i - 1] = m_arr[i];
      }
      --m_size;
    }
  }

  bool empty() const { return m_size == 0; }

private:
  std::array<int, 5> m_arr = {0};
  int m_size = 0;
};
}; // namespace Q

int main() {
  Q::queue q;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    q.push(i);
  }

  while (!q.empty()) {
    if (q.front() % 2 == 0) {
      std::cout << q.front() << ' ';
    }
    q.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```